# Can't seem to get pexpect to print data from command

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I'm steadily working on how to ssh and parse data on a device by running a command. I have had a few questions along the way of this endeavor and much help with the questions I have asked. I'm now working with pexpect and I'm not seeing much in documentation with what I am doing. Basically I need to ssh in, as I said, and then run a command that will print out data, then get that data to print to my console.

Here is my code:

```
import pexpect
import pxssh
import getpass

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh www.example.com')
password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
child.sendline ('foo bar')
data = (child.read_nonblocking(size=1000, timeout=100))
print data
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
password:
foo bar
```

In the `foo bar` command the first line of the print out is `foo bar` so I am wondering if this is trying to print this data but only printing the first line. I add the `read_nonblocking(size=1000, timeout=100)` trying to set the size to be greater and a timeout to let the data print.

**UPDATE with PXSSH**

I have also tried to use the pxssh samples to do this and get only the list of commands that `foo` can run. I need to get the print out of `foo bar` which is the list of configs. **My guess is that you can't have commands with spaces?** Here is the code I have tried:

```
import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.force_password = True
    hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login (hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline ('foo bar')  # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print s.before         # print everything before the prompt.
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed on login."
    print str(e)
```

**Which gives me this back in console:**

```
pxssh failed on login.
could not set shell prompt
:

Session idle time out is disabled

SSH> unset PROMPT_COMMAND
   Error - Command [unset PROMPT_COMMAND] not found.
   foo [ bar | bart | ran | up
         | cmd | bee | hvac | monkey
         | selective | list | help ]
   check[v,nv,beep] [ list | help ]
   delete [ all | bee | neewb | stuff
          | up | cmd | fooconfig | root
          | app | list | hvac | monkey
          | selective | <filename> | confirmed | list | help ]
   exit [ help ]
   get [ vcf | nvcf | snmpcf | help ] [<filename>]
   verbose [ help ]
   help [ <command> | help ]
     up arrow - brings up old command lines
     down arrow - brings up newer command lines
     right arrow - moves cursor to the right
     left arrow - moves cursor to the left
     insert - inserts a space at the cursor
     delete - deletes character at the cursor
SSH> PS1='[PEXPECT]\$ '
   Error - Command [PS1='[PEXPECT]\$ '] not found.
   foo [ bar | bart | ran | up
         | cmd | bee | hvac | monkey
         | selective | list | help ]
   check[v,nv,beep] [ list | help ]
   delete [ all | bee | neewb | stuff
          | up | cmd | fooconfig | root
          | app | list | hvac | monkey
          | selective | <filename> | confirmed | list | help ]
   exit [ help ]
   get [ vcf | nvcf | snmpcf | help ] [<filename>]
   verbose [ help ]
   help [ <command> | help ]
     up arrow - brings up old command lines
     down arrow - brings up newer command lines
     right arrow - moves cursor to the right
     left arrow - moves cursor to the left
     insert - inserts a space at the cursor
     delete - deletes character at the cursor
```

And as I mentioned I'm just trying to get the console to print out the `foo bar` command configs. This is the code I had working with `python-exscript` before finding out I needed to work in older `Python 2.4`.

**CODE THAT I HAD WORKING IN EXSCRIPT THAT I NEED PEXPECT TO DO**

```
account = read_login()              
conn = SSH2()                       
conn.connect('example.com')     
conn.login(account)           

conn.execute('foo bar')
data = conn.response
conn.send('exit\r')               
conn.close()
print data
```

Any help on how to get this code to work is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The docstring of read_nonblocking says timeout isn't doing what you you think it's doing: "The timeout refers only to the amount of time to read at least one character. This is not effected by the 'size' parameter, so if you call read_nonblocking(size=100, timeout=30) and only one character is available right away then one character will be returned immediately. It will not wait for 30 seconds for another 99 characters to come in."

Comment: The usual way to use pexpect is to `child.expect(x)` where x is something that will be printed at the *end* of your output (e.g. the next prompt), and then grab the output from `child.before`.

Comment: @ThomasK Oh ok, so how can you, with `pexpect` run a command and get the output from that to print?

Comment: I was able to run `conn.execute('foo bar') data = conn.response print data` with `python-exscript` what is equivalent in `pexpect`? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the pxssh examples here: http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pxssh.html#pexpect.pxssh.pxssh

Comment: @ThomasK Thanks, I have tried from those examples as well and this will run the command `foo bar` and prints to the console ALL the `foo` commands available. It won't print the actual full `foo bar` config that it should.

Comment: pxssh tries to change the prompt to something unique and consistent that it can look for, but it assumes that it's talking to an sh style shell to do that, and that's evidently not the case here. If you can't change the shell on the remote system, you can set `s.auto_prompt_reset = False; s.PROMPT='SSH> '` before calling `s.login()`.

Comment: @ThomasK thanks for that, but that isn't working. I still only get commands and not the config I am looking for. This time without the `SSH>`

Comment: The good thing is that I get only one list of commands back, not multiple and just this error `unset PROMPT_COMMAND Error - Command [unset PROMPT_COMMAND] not found.`

Comment: Looking at the code, I think you actually need to pass `auto_prompt_reset=False` to `s.login()`, not set it as an attribute. That's a mistake in the docs.

Comment: Thanks but that seemed to not help either @ThomasK

Comment: Can you show me what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue. I was missing a `s.prompt()`

```
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=60, maxread=2000000)
    s.force_password = True
    hostname = raw_imput('hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('password: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.PROMPT= 'SSH> '
    s.login (hostname, username, password, auto_prompt_reset=False)
    s.prompt()
    s.sendline('foo bar')
    s.prompt()
    data = s.before
    print data
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed on login."
    print str(e)
```

Comment: Do you need just 1 or for every sendline?